# CLI/C++ CodeDom parser error "Unknown type", designer won't appear

Tags: c++-cli, windows-forms-designer

I have an old project made in Visual studio 2015 and I want to reopen it in Visual studio 2017. The project contains several forms but none of them will open without giving the following error:

> C++ CodeDOM parser error: Line: 104, Column: 21 --- Unknown type ''. Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced. If this type is a part of your development project, make sure that the project has been successfully built.

The mentioned line is: `this->components = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::Container());`

As far as I can remember I never changed a thing in the `InitializeComponent` part.

If needed I can copy a full header file, into the question.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: C++/CLI Winforms apps are getting pretty cranky in later VS versions.  Be sure to rebuild the project before trying to open the form.

Comment: Yea I rebuilded the project a couple of times. But I can't open it. I've searched for more Unknown type errors, but atleast they gave a type. Mine is complete blank...

Comment: Seems like the UI is messed up. the resolution is bigger, the text is bigger than it should... very odd. Even installed VS 2015 and I still have the same issue. Seems like my new laptop is doing something wrong (same OS... Windows 7 Pro)

Comment: Hey @Bart, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I ran into this, but it was after upgrading the version of .NET I reference. Putting it back to v4.5.2 let's it work again, but I still haven't found a way to get it to work with newer .NET versions.

Answer (score 1):

I once and still see this issue often where it says `Unknown Type: ''` with a blank type.

After a lot of hits and tries, I finally deleted everything inside `.vs` folder and it started working back.

Comment: Thanks! That's the only thing that helps.